# GAE and Facebook auth

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

I have a app using Google account authentication, i receive a cookie every time the user connects and i make simple HTTP calls using the cookie. Is there something similar i can do with the fb token with a Google App Engine back end?

Comment: python, the app is android(java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate users on your GAE app via FB, you need to implement a server-side auth flow as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I know you need Python, but still: I implemented GAE-FB auth in Java and released it as part of an OSS project: [LeanEngine](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Server)

There is also an [Android client](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Android) - see [`LoginDialog`](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Android/blob/master/lean-android-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/LoginDialog.java).